# Building ffmpeg for ARM with libopencore-amr support

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg

I am trying to build ffmpeg with opencore-amr and libx264 support, I found this build script http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpeg4android/, this compiles as expected, the resultant binary works fine on the device and --enable-libx264 appears in the output of the binary when I pass no arguments.

However when I try to include support for libopencore-amr it doesnt seem to work, I have installed libopencore-amr and libopencore-amr-devel (I should add that I have tried this whole procedure on both fedora and ubuntu). I modified the Android_Configure.mk file so that it looks like this:

```
FF_CONFIGURATION_STRING := \
    --arch=$(TARGET_ARCH) \
    --target-os=linux \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --cross-prefix=$(NDK_CROSS_
PREFIX) \
    --sysroot=$(NDK_SYSROOT) \
    --enable-shared \
    --enable-static \
    --enable-libopencore-amrnb   <-- i've added this line
```

However when I run ./configure I see:

```
libopencore-amrnb support no
libopencore-amrwb support no
```

Despite this the build goes well with zero compilation errors. When I run ffmpeg on the device everything seems to work however there is definitely no support for amrnb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure libopencore exists in the sysroot against which you are compiling, and thats where --sysroot parameter points to. The chance is there is no libopencore there, so configure script disables it.

Comment: Hi, so what exactly should i put in sysroot? The downloaded opencore package?

Comment: You should put opencore library compiled for the target platform.